# iPad maps: hide location circle

Tags: ipad, maps, geolocation

Is ther a way to hide the blue location circle on the iPad maps? I know I could disable wifi, but I still want to be able to access the maps. What I am trying to do is to zoom all the way out in satellite mode and see if I can find things without any labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(For iOS 6)*

1. Open Settings.app
2. Tap "Privacy"
3. Tap "Location Services"
4. Scroll down until you see the "Maps" app
5. Turn the switch "Off"

This will effectively disable the the blue dot. If you have [Google Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps/id585027354?mt=8) or [Google Earth](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-earth/id293622097?mt=8) installed, you can also disable the location services for those apps as well. You will find each app that uses location services listed under the main on/off switch.

Comment: No need to turn it off globally.  Maps has its own setting.

Comment: @asmeurer, thank you for pointing that out. I edited my answer. I looked there - because I figured it would have it's own switch - but didn't find it. Obviously wasn't careful enough.